# resolver duda con booleanos, estoy en capacitación

Tags: python, booleano, funcion

hola soy nuevo estoy en curso de python y necesito resolver una función, tengo que hacer que usuario ingrese una respuesta y que esta respuesta me de un bool según la misma

```
extincion = input(" la especie se extingio ? si o no ?:   ")
    if extincion == si:
        print("la especie se extingio")
    else:
        print("la especio sigue")
```

esto en la capacitación no me lo explicaron se los agradecería

Comment: Buen día, ¿Te solicitaron crear una función o únicamente hacer una pregunta al usuario y devolver un booleano?

Comment: si correcto se realiza la pregunta y tendría que devolver un bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola lucassh bienvenido a stackoverflow.

Hay un error en tu código, ya que la variable extincion tienes que compararla con un string literal "si".

Actualmente tu código lanza un error: "NameError: name 'si' is not defined"

Para corregirlo cambia la segunda línea de esta forma:

```
if extincion == "si":
```

Como información adicional, en Python se utilizan las indentaciones o espacios para marcar los bloques de código. [Indentación en Python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/indentacion-en-python-con-ejemplos/)

Tu código completo debe quedar así:

```
extincion = input(" la especie se extingio ? si o no ?:   ")
if extincion == "si":
    print("la especie se extingio")
else:
    print("la especie sigue")
```

Fíjate que las sentencias if y else estan al mismo nivel, en cambio los print están con una indentación.

Espero haberte ayudado,

Saludos!